# Does ASP.Net Core 1.0 support WebForm projects

Tags: webforms, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Does **ASP.Net Core 1.0** support .Net WebForm projects?  Or it is an MVC only environment? Also can I create classic web services(asmx) there?

Comment: Since WebForms weren't (IIRC) part of ASP.NET vNext/5.0, I doubt they're part of Core 1.0 (which is just 5.0 renamed).  As for classic web services (.ASMX) - *why*? :)

Comment: http://www.codemag.com/article/1501061

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: No, ASP.NET Core does not contain Web Forms or Web Services.

Long answer:
Depends on your meaning of "support". If you aim to run ASP.NET Core project on top of *CoreCLR* and *CoreFX*, then the answer is no: ASP.NET Core will contain support only for MVC ja Web API -projects (which are the same thing in ASP.NET Core).

If you can run on full .NET Framework, then ASP.NET Web Forms can co-exist with ASP.NET Core. The Web Forms will be the same Web Forms they are today on System.Web. In this scenario you would host your web forms in a different project (normal ASP.NET 4.x application) on IIS and ASP.NET Core would live in it's own application on Kestrel.

Comment: Do you have any documentation links for this information on co-existing?

Comment: What kind of documentation you are looking for? 

After reading my answer now again, I find that one could interpret it wrong. You can definately have have Full framework and .NET Core on a single machine (running different applications). But if you are looking for a solution to run Web Forms and ASP.NET Core MVC **in the same project**, it will not be possible (or sensible: in theory you could have a "web forms middleware" that can host your .aspx, but implementing it will be an interesting task).

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's anything in MSDN or other Microsoft documentation that specifically states this. Would be good to add more credibility to the answer for others landing here.

Comment: Having it as two separate applications is easy but the question should be is can one share the Authentication and Authorization (ASP.net core Identity)with both so one only signs in once

Answer (score 1):

A need to use .NET technologies not available for .NET Core

Some .NET Framework technologies are not available in .NET Core. Some of them will be available in later .NET Core releases, but others don’t apply to the new application patterns targeted by .NET Core and may never be available. The following list shows the most common technologies not found in .NET Core 1.0:

ASP.NET Web Forms applications: ASP.NET Web Forms is only available on the .NET Framework, so you cannot use ASP.NET Core / .NET Core for this scenario. Currently there are no plans to bring ASP.NET Web Forms to .NET Core.

ASP.NET Web Pages applications: ASP.NET Web Pages are not included in ASP.NET Core 1.0, although it is planned to be included in a future release as explained in the .NET Core roadmap.

ASP.NET SignalR server/client implementation. At .NET Core 1.0 release timeframe (June 2016), ASP.NET SignalR is not available for ASP.NET Core (neither client or server), although it is planned to be included in a future release as explained in the .NET Core roadmap. Preview state is available at the Server-side and Client Library GitHub repositories.

WCF services implementation. Even when there’s a WCF-Client library to consume WCF services from .NET Core, as of June 2016, WCF server implementation is only available on the .NET Framework. This scenario is not part of the current plan for .NET Core but it’s being considered for the future.

Workflow related services: Windows Workflow Foundation (WF), Workflow Services (WCF + WF in a single service) and WCF Data Services (formerly known as “ADO.NET Data Services”) are only available on the .NET Framework and there are no plans to bring them to .NET Core.

Language support: Visual Basic and F# don’t currently have tooling support .NET Core, but both will be supported in Visual Studio 2017 and later versions of Visual Studio.

source [Choosing between .net Core and .net Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/choosing-core-framework-server)