# Migrating ASMX web service to .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, web-services

I am migrating an .NET 4.72 website to .NET Core 6.0. I have an ASMX web service. In .NET Core, I know that System.Web.Services.WebService does not exist. How do I migrate this code? Do I create a .NET 4.72 class library and reference it in my web project?

Here is my code:

```
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://developer.intuit.com/", Name = "QBWebService", Description = "QuickBooks Web Service Connector")]
public class QBWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

Comment: Similar question was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326554/does-asp-net-core-1-0-support-webform-projects . But recently Core WCF was released which can help you with migration - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/